# Why does awk's printf interpret character values greater than 127 as multi-byte characters?

Tags: awk, unicode, ascii

The ASCII character range is from 0 to 127, and within that range, awk's printf with the %c format specifier outputs one byte of data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 97}'
a

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 127}' | xxd
00000000: 7f

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 127}' | xxd -b
00000000: 01111111
```

But for values greater than 127, it will print out multiple bytes:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 128}' | xxd
00000000: c280

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 128}' | xxd -b
00000000: 11000010 10000000
```

What is the significance of 0xc280, and why does awk output that character instead of 0x80?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. 11000010 starts a two-byte sequence (the first two bits set followed by a clear bit), and the significant bits are 00010000000 (the last five bits of the first byte, and the last six bits of the second byte), which is 128.

AWK is outputting this because your locale is set to use UTF-8; you can switch to a non-UTF-8 locale to see the difference:

```
$ LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c", 128}' | xxd -b
00000000: 10000000
```

Comment: Failed on Termux, as `en_US.UTF-8` is the only available locale and my AWK is refering GAWK; can be solved by either `env -i awk` to call AWK on Android itself, or `gawk -b`: with GAWK-specific option.

Answer (score -5):

One trick to get awk to print out any arbitrary byte, regardless of whether your locale is UTF8 or POSIX or C, is to add a large multiple of 256 to the unsigned byte ordinance value to bring the new number above `0x10FFFF`, the limit of Unicode 14 spec.

Here's a demo of how to access arbitrary bytes in gawk byte mode to print out UTF8-encoded characters. The same method can also be used in gawk unicode mode to access any byte:

```
 gawk -e 'BEGIN { printf("%c",50000) }' | od -baxco -t dC

0000000   354 215 220                                                    
           ?  8d  90                                                    
             8dec    0090                                                
          썐  **  **                                                    
           106754  000220                                                
          -20-115-112                                                    
0000003

% gawk -b -e 'BEGIN { printf("%c%c%c",
                             (-20)+8^8,
                            (-115)+8^8,
                            (-112)+8^8) }' | od -baxco -t dC
0000000   354 215 220                                                    
           ?  8d  90                                                    
             8dec    0090                                                
          썐  **  **                                                    
           106754  000220                                                
          -20-115-112                                                    
0000003

% gawk -e 'BEGIN { printf("%c%c%c%c",\
                                      \
                   0xAB+8^8, 0xBA+8^8, \
                   0xCA+8^8, 0xFE+8^8) }' \
 | god --endian=big -baxco -t dCxI

0000000  253  272  312  376
           +    :    J    ~
             abba      cafe
           ?    ?    ?    ?
           125672    145376
         -85  -70  -54   -2
                   abbacafe
0000004
```

This method works regardless of your locale settings.

For mawk-1, mawk2-beta, and nawk, you can also subtract 256 from the unsigned byte value and do `printf("%c")` using negative numbers. gawk used to also allow that, but recent versions might have disabled it.

Comment: I probably have a slightly old version of gawk at hand, but with `gawk 'BEGIN { printf("%c", 0 + 8^8) }' | od -tx1`, I get the output bytes `f9 80 80 80 80`, i.e. it seems to print that UTF-8 too. Same-o up to `2^31-1` or so, I guess that's the since-prohibited upper range. Anyway, it means that one might want to use e.g. 2^32, or 8^11 (2^33)  as the offset instead.

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning that [gawk actually documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html) that it falls back to using the low 8 bits if the conversion fails. Without knowing that it's documented, this might seem dangerously fiddly, as something that has a risk of breaking in a future version. Well, I guess it still could, if the locale definitions and/or the UTF-8 specification change (again).

Comment: actually, worse, `gawk 'BEGIN { printf("%c", 255 + 2^32) }' | od -tx1` gives me `c3 bf`.

Comment: if you have the older variants of gawk, then subtract 8^8 instead of adding it. I'd advise against >2^31 as that may be subject to wrap-around : C3 BF is exactly U+00FF. Yes UTF8 can change, but it'd be quite some time before Unicode spec start bumping against this 8^8, seeing that it's some 15x larger than current upper limit  : gawk -e 'BEGIN { printf("%c|%c|%c",255+8^8,255+8^11,255+2^31) }' | odview
         377   |   ÿ  **   | 377
          377 174 303 277 174 377          255 124 195 191 124 255
           ff  7c  c3  bf  7c  ff

Comment: what gawk documentation say & how it actually behaves r 2 things. gawk's docs never explicitly mentioned -256 or +8^8 tricks either. even the low-8-bit fallback part is no longer universally true as the most recent versions of gawk has removed  the ability 4 neg values to properly cast down to unsigned char, something that still exists in mawk-1.3.4, mawk 1.9.9.6, and macos nawk. if u wanna play it safe, u can always try casting into UTF-16 hi/lo surrogate range of 0xD800-0xDFFF, which does the trick too. i just prefer 8^8 since I'm not aware of any locale setting that has code pts that large

Comment: well, if the documentation doesn't match the behaviour, that's a bug (in one of them), and should be reported. But if the documentation doesn't say anything, the behaviour might be unintended and subject to change.

Comment: Anyway, you mentioned in meta that you "offered a clean solution that is completely agnostic to locale settings", and wondered about the downvote, but it seems to me now that even if the solution is locale-agnostic, it's not as _version-agnostic_ as one might hope. Having to use a negative offset for one version, and a positive for another is a pain. And things like that may also well affect how people vote.

Comment: it's supposed to be agnostic, but I have no idea why your version of gawk would behave so strangely. in any case, if you want UTF16 surrogate edition to get any byte, here's the code : % gawk -e 'BEGIN { s=""; for(x0=(x=1+0xD800)+255;x<x0;) { s=s""sprintf("%c%c%c",x++,x++,x++) }; arr[(x=split(s,arr,//))-x++]=sprintf("%c",0); print (arr[255]=="\377") }' …… but why would you be concerned about matching the latest documentation when your gawk is a legacy variant ?

Comment: ps : "f9 80 80 80 80" isn't UTF-8 at all, or for that matter, UTF32 either. Current UTF-8 doesn't have any bytes higher than F4, and none of the current code points call for 4+ continuation bytes. I know some ancient literature mentions up to 7-byte variants, but those haven't been part of the official spec for quite some time already (as in, perhaps a decade or more). in terms of being version-agnostic, (a) i never promised that, and (b) i don't have time to go test it against every legacy gawk out there

Comment: @ilkkachu : i can't speak for every legacy awk variant and their caveats - i could only tell you what i've tested on my system using gawk 5.1.1, both byte-mode and unicode-mode, mawk 1.3.4, mawk 1.9.9.6, and macos 12.1 built-in nawk. tragically, those downvoting me couldn't even offer any better solutions. if you're on gawk 3.x then i think we can call it a day

Comment: Those downvoting you (which now include me) do not consider this a solution to the question asked since it is instead giving a (useful and interesting) solution to a completley different question: "How can I print an arbitrary byte in awk". That isn't the question asked here. This question is asking "_What is the significance of 0xc280, and why does awk output that character instead of 0x80?_".

Comment: and yet the highest voted solution involves having to arbitrarily force a locale setting in order to get 0x80 when in fact none is needed, as I've shown - to mix and match both unicode and byte-level ops is clearly doable in a single invocation of any awk, unless it's nawk on macos, which is really messed up regarding its multi-byte setup. Having to force locale setting is equivalent to harming one's own foot just to fit into Cinderella's glass slippers.